# Extract email address from multi lines with line break

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have a list which contains name, email address, location, date and time, etc.

From the list, I'd like to extract only name and email address.

The original text representation is like,

```
Email address: abc103@gmail.com
City/town: Hills, United States
Last access: Saturday, 6 January 2018, 8:46 PM  (17 secs)
```

So, In the python list, it shows up like below.

```
import re

lst = [['name1', 'Email address: abc103@gmail.com\nCity/town: Hills , United States\nLast access: Saturday, 6 January 2018, 8:46 PM  (17 secs)'], ['name2', 'Email address: cde123@example.com\nCity/town: San Francisco, United States\nLast access: Saturday, 6 January 2018, 8:46 PM  (48 secs)'], ['name3', 'Email address: nnn9@something.com\nCity/town: Fremont, United States\nLast access: Saturday, 6 January 2018, 8:43 PM  (3 mins 21 secs)'], ['name4', 'City/town: Tenafly, United States\nLast access: Saturday, 6 January 2018, 8:36 PM  (10 mins 14 secs)'],... list goes on.

for i in range(0, len(lst)):
    extract = re.findall(r'(^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$)', lst[i][1],re.MULTILINE)
    lst[i][1] = extract

print(lst)
```

However, the output is like,

```
[['name1', []], ['name2', []], ['name3', []], ....
```

What's wrong with my regex?
How do I apply re.findall to multi-line with line breaks?

Comment: Try losing the preceding '^' and the trailing '$'.

Comment: The lines contain no matches to your regular expression.  If you were to remove the beginning and end of line anchors, you should get some matches. `^` matches at beginning of file or just after a newline; `$` similarly just before a newline as well as at the end of file even if there isn't a newline there. Beginning / end of string qualify as beginning / end of "file" in this context.

Comment: `r'[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+\@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+'` use this regex

Comment: @tripleee : +1 also, `@` needs `\`

Comment: Huh? No, `@` is just a regular character in Python regex. Maybe you are being confused by Perl's usage of this character to interpolate arrays.

Comment: The regex isn't really adequate; the main flaw is that requires the domain part to have exactly two labels (it will fail on `yahoo.co.uk` etc). Also, it will reject e.g. domain names with a dash in the TLD. There is a number of characters in the localpart which are permitted which the regex doesn't include in the character class before `@` but more fundamentally, using regex to identify email addresses is problematic in the general case (though ignoring some of the allowed formats which are unusual in practice gets you pretty far).

Comment: Rolling your own regex is almost inexcusable, though finding a (broadly speaking) *correct* one is challenging, too. Try http://emailregex.com/ for an *allegedly* 99.9% correct one, with a number of variations -- though notice that sadly their *Python* regex is flawed in exactly the same ways.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me :

```
import re
lst = [['name1', 'Email address: abc103@gmail.com\nCity/town: Hills , United States\nLast access: Saturday, 6 January 2018, 8:46 PM  (17 secs)'], ['name2', 'Email address: cde123@example.com\nCity/town: San Francisco, United States\nLast access: Saturday, 6 January 2018, 8:46 PM  (48 secs)'], ['name3', 'Email address: nnn9@something.com\nCity/town: Fremont, United States\nLast access: Saturday, 6 January 2018, 8:43 PM  (3 mins 21 secs)'], ['name4', 'City/town: Tenafly, United States\nLast access: Saturday, 6 January 2018, 8:36 PM  (10 mins 14 secs)']]
#lst[0][1].findall('([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.][a-zA-Z]+)', expand=True)
for i in range(0, len(lst)):
    extract = re.findall(r'([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.][a-zA-Z]+)', lst[i][1],re.MULTILINE)
    lst[i][1] = extract
```

print(lst)

the output :

```
[['name1', ['abc103@gmail.com']], ['name2', ['cde123@example.com']], ['name3', ['nnn9@something.com']], ['name4', []]]
```